# SAPUI5 Routing targetview shown at the bottom

Tags: routes, sapui5

I want to navigate from one view to another like href = Target. It is working fine but the target view is shown at the bottom of the initial view instead of being shown in another window. I can still see both views.

```
onGotoSecond: function() {
            var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            router.navTo("second");
        },
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: In case you are using a NavContainer like App or SplitApp, check if you have added the target in the App / SplitApp in the XML view itself. What I mean is, make sure that the NavContainer or it's subclass does not contain references to the views you are attempting to navigate to. You might need to post more information on the view and controller to get a better answer.

Comment: how has your manifest been set up?

Comment: @Sid thank you for replying. My manifest was correct. There some error in the first view.